# Specify parent component for a facet to render header within dialog component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to specify the parent component for `f:facet` to assign it as a child of a `p:dialog` component ? I've been trying out this but no header is rendered.

```
<p:dialog id="pageDialog">
    <p:outputPanel>
        <p:outputPanel>
            <f:facet name="header" parent="pageDialog" >
                Followed Topics
            </f:facet>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Just make it a child of the `<p:dialog/>` or just use the `header` attribute of the dialog. Why do you have a `<p:outputPanel/>` inside a `<p:outputPanel/>`?

Comment: Thanks, I know that. This is not my exact code but a simplified version. These nested `outputPanel`(s) are required for my case to render one out of several content types inside same dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. The `<f:facet>` is [by specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/facet.html) specific to the closest parent component.

You might want to extend `<p:outputPanel>` to a custom component which can do the job. You can get, add and remove the facets via among others the from `UIComponent` inherited [`getFacets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getFacets%28%29) method. Do the following job during `preRenderView` event:

```
UIComponent headerFacet = getFacets().remove("header");

if (headerFacet != null) {
    UIComponent dialog = getItSomehowPerhapsBasedOnAnAttribute();
    dialog.getFacets().put("header", headerFacet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got confused by the newly added `parent` attribute to the JSF components. Could you clarify what is it used for ?

Comment: That attribute doesn't exist at all. I assumed that it was just careless random guessing on your side without actually looking at the attribute listing of the tag documentation. Note that the "by specification" link in my answer points to the `<f:facet>` tag documentation which clearly describes the nature of the tag in the introduction and lists all available attributes (there's actually only one).